# Inequalities of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given a fixed number $x>0$. Could we choose $y$ and $z$ that depend on $x$ such that
$y=z+x$, $0<z<1$ and $y>1$?

If $x>1$, then we can choose $z=\frac{1}{x}$ and $y=\frac{1}{x}+x$.

But, I can't do it for $0<x\leq 1$. How to overcome this case?

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: $z=1-\frac{x}{2}$ and $y=1+\frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\ge 1$ then any $z\in(0,1)$ gives a correct result.

If $x<1$ then by choosing some $z$ such that $z+x>1$ you have the correct result.  For example, $z=1-\frac{x}{2}$.  In this case $y=1+\frac{x}{2}$.

You can write this as: $$z=\left\{\begin{align}\frac{1}{2} & \text{if } x \ge 1 \\ 1-\frac{x}{2} & \text{if } 0<x<1 \end{align} \right. .$$

Although it doesn't seem necessary for the problem, this has the advantage of being continuous.